# Not able to start ActiveMQ as a service under Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-services, activemq-classic, windows-server-2008-r2, access-denied

We are trying to launch ActiveMQ as a service on a Windows Server 2008 R2 server, but we get a "1067 error" and in the log file we see this:

```
FATAL | wrapper | 2012/03/12 16:34:54 | Critical error: wait for JVM process failed
STATUS | wrapper | 2012/03/12 16:41:00 | --> Wrapper Started as Service
STATUS | wrapper | 2012/03/12 16:41:00 | Launching a JVM...
FATAL | wrapper | 2012/03/12 16:41:00 | Unable to execute Java command. Accesso negato. (0x5)
FATAL | wrapper | 2012/03/12 16:41:00 | "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\
```

"accesso negato" means "access is denied" (Italian). The Java path seems correct. We tried all these combinations:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\bin
```

folders in which the java*.exe executables are present (we have installed JRE6, JRE7 and JDK; before trying JRE7/JDK1.7, we had installed just JRE6).

All the access privileges seem to be assigned to the folders and in the property of ActiveMQ service we gave the rights of Administrator (maximum rights). In a forum, we found out to remark the field "jetty" in the configuration file, but it hasn't solved anything.

Is there something wrong with the way in which we installed/launched ActiveMQ or incompatibilities with our environment/operating system?

Comment: we tried also to launch manually ActiveMQ (activemq.exe command) bypassing the wrapper and the relative service. This works, but for ignorance we don't know if it is functionally the same thing. A workaround could be a more verbose log, but we don't know if there is this chance.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue. The issue for me was that RabbitMQ was also running as a service and binding to the same port. Stopping RabbitMQ allowed ActiveMQ to start. I could have also changed ports.

Run Wrapper.exe in a command window to see the error.
If it is a port issue you can run the command `netstat -a -b` to see what is binding to the port.

Here are answers to how to change your port if needed:

[How can I change default port number of Activemq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082404/how-can-i-change-default-port-number-of-activemq)

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the bat file (\bin\win32\activemq.bat) as administrator.
If this works, it means you have not correctly installed the ActiveMQ service to be run under an account that has the administrator privileges.

You need the 64-bit wrapper (by default ActiveMQ comes with 32-bit only).

A few options there:

- Download the latest 64-bit wrapper available in [the website](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp)
- Launch the process via jsvc (see [this blog post](http://blog.bigrocksoftware.com/2010/10/07/commons-daemon-procrun-as-a-java-service-wrapper-for-activemq/) describing the process)
- Update to the latest 5.6 ActiveMQ that supports this out of the box (the previous 2 entries were only for releases pre 5.6

Comment: The .bat file has always been run as administrator. Besides, the user defined in theproper label of ActiveMQ service proprieties has manually been defined as Administrator with the correct pw.

Comment: Can you add the contents of the wrapper.conf inside the initial post?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below items:

1. Check if the port is blocked by other services; you can change the port from `ActiveMQ.xml` if it is.
2. Check that `JAVA_HOME` is available and is accessible to the user
3. You can delete the Kaha DB folder (`activeMQ\data\kahadb`) and install again

This worked for me