# How can I change default port number of Activemq

Tags: java, apache, jms, activemq-classic, java-ee-7

I am using `Windows 7` OS. I downloaded `apache-activemq-5.8.0.zip` from these [Link](http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-580-release.html) and extracted in `C:\Users\Infratab Bangalore\Desktop\Queueing\apache-activemq-5.8.0` directory.

While `Activemq` initialization time I read `Pre-Installation Requirements` concept from these [Link](http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html#GettingStarted-TestingtheInstallation).

I already installed `apache-maven-3.0.5` in my system.For my conformation I run the following command in my system.

```
   mvn -version
```

I am getting the following message,So `Maven` is installed successfully.

```
 Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 19:21:
 28+0530)
 Maven home: P:\Software\apache-maven-3.0.5
 Java version: 1.7.0_21, vendor: Oracle Corporation
 Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre
 Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
 OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

I downloaded `geronimo-spec-corba-1.0.jar` from these [Link](http://people.apache.org/repository/geronimo-spec/jars/) and set `classpth`.

[image]

I started `Activemq` initialization in the following way.

```
  C:\Users\Infratab Bangalore\Desktop\Queueing\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin>activemq
```

I am getting error,So I tested whether `61616(Activemq default port no)` is in active with the following statement.

```
  C:\Users\Infratab Bangalore>netstat -an|find "61616"
   TCP    0.0.0.0:61616          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
   TCP    [::]:61616             [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

Finally I understand `61616` port is active so I want to change my port number.

1. Am I right, what I am thinking?
2. How can I install `Activemq`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe your problem is there is already something running on port 61616.  (It could be another instance of ActiveMQ you started on accident).

You can change the port for ActiveMQ in the activemq.xml file.  Just do a find on 61616 and replace it with the port you would like to use (it should be in the `<transportConnector>` tag with the name `openwire`).

You do not have to install ActiveMQ, simply launch `activemq.bat` in the bin folder to start the standalone service.

Answer (score 1):

In the bin folder, there is an activemq.bat file. Just run that like so

```
activemq.bat start broker:tcp//<ipAddres>:<desiredPort>
example: activemq.bat start broker:tcp//localhost:61617
```